# Find a sequence such that $\liminf a_n^{1/n}=1/4,\ \limsup a_n^{1/n}=1/3$

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

How to construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $1>a_n>a_{n+1}>0$ for all $n>0$ and 
$$
\liminf a_n^{1/n}=1/4,\ \limsup a_n^{1/n}=1/3.
$$ 
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use displayed math in titles because it creates large gaps on the front page.

Answer (score 2):

This is not complete, but is probably enough to be getting on with (and maybe someone else will fill in the gaps).

First, to avoid writing lots of irritating fractions, I will indicate how to find an increasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive reals such that

$$\liminf a_n^{1/n} = 3 \text{ and } \limsup a_n^{1/n} = 4,$$
since we can then get a solution for the original question by using the sequence $\{\frac{1}{a_n}\}$.

Note that putting $a_n = 3^n$ would give a sequence with $\liminf a_n^{1/n} = 3$, and putting $a_n = 4^n$ would give a sequence with $\limsup a_n^{1/n} = 4$, so we need to "interleave" these two sequences (and fill in some gaps) to satisfy all requirements.

Choose $a_1$ to be $3$, then $a_2$ to be $4^2$, then look for the next $k$ such that $3^k>a_2$, then then next $k$ such that $4^k>a_3$ etc, - not worrying for the moment about the missing terms:

```
n           3^n         4^n
1           3           
2                       16
3           27          
4                       256
5                       ??
6           729         
7                       16384
8                       ??
9           19683           
10                      1048576
11                      ??
12                      ??
13          1594323         
14                      268435456
15                      ??
16                      ??
17                      ??
18          387420489           
19                      274877906944
```

Now we fill in the gaps by simply increasing the previous term $4^n$ by 1 each time, and "it is easily seen that" we get:

```
n           3^n         4^n         a_n^1/n
1           3                       3
2                       16          4
3           27                      3
4                       256         4
5                       257         3.034
6           729                     3
7                       16384           4
8                       16385           3.364
9           19683                       3
10                      1048576         4
11                      1048577         3.526
12                      1048578         3.175
13          1594323                     3
14                      268435456       4
15                      268435457       3.647
16                      268435458       3.364
17                      268435459       3.132
18          387420489                   3
19                      274877906944        4
```

I would be grateful for anyone who can show me how to write this out in a sensible way!

Answer (score 2):

Both sequences ${1\over 3^n}$ $\>(n\geq0)$ and ${1\over 4^n}$ $\>(n\geq1)$ tend to zero. By alternating between these two sequences we can produce a monotone sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ with the required properties.

Define the strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\geq1}$  as follows: Put $n_1:=1$ and for $k\geq1$ define recursively
$$n_{2k}:=\min\bigl\{j\>|\>j>n_{2k-1},\  4^j>3^{n_{2k-1}}\bigr\}, \quad
n_{2k+1}:=\min\bigl\{j\>|\> j>n_{2k},\ 3^j>4^{n_{2k}}\bigr\}\ .$$
Then let
$$a_{n_{2k-1}}:={1\over 3^{n_{2k-1}}}\ ,\quad a_{n_{2k}}:={1\over 4^{n_{2k}}}\qquad(k\geq1)\ .$$
It follows that $a_{n_{r+1}}<a_{n_r}$ for all $r\geq1$. Finally for $n_r<\ell<n_{r+1}$ choose the $a_\ell$ equidistant between $a_{n_r}$ and $a_{n_{r+1}}$.

In this way the $a_\ell$ are monotonically decreasing; and furthermore one has ${\root l \of a_\ell}={1\over 3}$ as well as ${\root l \of a_\ell}={1\over 4}$ for infinitely many $\ell$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n=\frac1{4^n}$ and $c_n=\frac1{3^n}$. It is clear if for each $n$ we have either $b_n\le a_n\le c_n$ and, moreover, $a_n=b_n$ is fulfilled for infinitely many $n$'s, then $\liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac14$. Similarly if we have have $a_n=c_n$ infinitely often, then $\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac13$.

It is very simple to achieve this -- we simply divide $\mathbb N$ into two infinite sets and put $a_n=b_n$ for numbers from one set and $a_n=c_n$ for numbers from the other set.

The question is: Can we modify this somehow to get monotone sequence?

---

I will deal with a slightly simpler problem where I only require $a_{n+1}\le a_n$. (I do not think it should be very difficult to modify this to a strictly decreasing sequence.)

Let us describe our sequence inductively:

- We start by choosing $a_n=\frac1{3^n}$ for $a\in [A_0,B_0)$, where $A_0=1$, and $B_0$ is arbitrary.
- Next we put $a_n=\frac1{4^n}$ for $a\in [B_0,C_0)$. Again $C_0$ can be chosen arbitrarily, we only want $C_0>B_0$.
- On the next interval the sequence will be constant, i.e., we put $a_n=\frac1{4^{C_0}}$ for $n\in[C_0,A_1)$. The number $N_1$ will be start of the next interval, i.e., we want to define $a_{A_1}=\frac1{3^{A_1}}$. We want to do this in such way, that our sequence will be monotone. For this we need
  $$\frac1{3^{A_1}} \le \frac1{4^{C^0}}.$$
  We also want that our sequence is always between $\frac1{4^n}$ and $\frac1{3^n}$. So we want
  $$\frac1{4^{C^0}} \le \frac1{3^{A_1-1}}.$$
  So we have to choose
  $$A_1=\min\{k\in\mathbb N; \frac1{3^k} \le \frac1{4^{C^0}}\}.$$

Now we can repeat the same process inductively.

---

The above does not give an explicit formula for $a_n$. If you really want such a formula, you can try to play with choice of $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$.